# How to ignore transient field define inside the object which is in List of objects using GSON

Tags: java, gson

I have two classes A and B:
Below is the code :

```
 Class A{
  private String field1;
  private List<B> list = new ArrayList<B>();
 }

Class B{
 private transient field2;
}
```

Using gson API how to exclude transient field in class B. excludeFieldsWithModifiers method  in GsonBuilder class will exclude transient field only of class A but not of class B as class A contains List of object of class B and field2 is define in class B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Gson` serializes `List<B>`, it will actually serialize list contents. And, of course, it will skip transient fields in content models.

Comment: @IIyaGulya so you mean to say that class has to implements Serializable interface for that.

Comment: No, they never said you must implement `Serializable`. GSON uses reflection to determine what it will and will not serialize for you, and it does _not_ serialize transient fields.

Answer (score 1):

By default, if you mark a field as transient, it will be excluded. As well, if a field is marked as "static" then by default it will be excluded. 
If you have used the following statement somewhere for Class B, it will include the transient fields and exclude only the specified modifier, "static" in the said case

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.STATIC).create();
```

You can add transient modifier to exclude transient fields as well:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.STATIC, Modifier.TRANSIENT).create();
```

This will exclude all the transient fields and any previous modifier that you added.